# Central mass archiving change for business partners

Tags: abap, jobs, sap-erp

I think this is a long shot, but here's my problem:

I'd like to flag many business partners for archiving, at once, in a background job.

There is BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE and BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE but both of these take single business partners as their import parameters. I think that looping and calling this function wouldn't make sense as I'd just have 50,000 background jobs. I'd like to have one backgroud job, with all the business partners given. Passing a standard table and not a structure dumps the function.  Is there any way to get more data into a structure, or another way entirely to do this?

```
    ls_central-centralarchivingflag = 'X'.
    ls_central_x-centralarchivingflag = 'X'.
   CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE' IN BACKGROUND TASK
    EXPORTING
    businesspartner                   = ls_partner_bapi   (Here, many bpartners)
    centraldata                       = ls_central
    centraldata_x                     = ls_central_x
    TABLES
    return                            = lt_return.
```

Comment: Why do you assume that you would have 50k background jobs instead of a loop inside a single background job? Why would you want to call the function module in a background task in the first place? (note: task != job!)

Comment: A loop inside of a single background task is what I wanted, but it wasn't executing. I made a function module to run in background, passing the table and then looping over it inside the FM with the BUPA call in the loop -  but nothing ever came up in SM37 or SM58 and no DB changes were made even with commit / commit functions.

Comment: And without more details on the return values, nobody will ever know why...

Comment: I don't know enough to give you the return values, or even see them. It wasn't returning anything. I'm not withholding info :)    But! My solution is to write all of the partners to a DB table from the analysis program, and then have a second program that I can run in the background select directly from this DB and mark those partners for archiving. Since both take a while to run, it's okay (best) for me to do them separately. Doing them all at once in the foreground is what led to a dump in the first place - there are too many to be changed this way on that system.

Comment: It's always preferable to use standard functionality, than bunch of Z-constructions.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not the one making the decisions :D  I wanted to just export them to excel and upload them to MASS' selection screen.

Answer (score 4):

Use Mass Maintenance Tool (tcode `MASS` or `MASSD`) instead. It can be used to change any objects in batch, including business partners.

[image]

Here is the [manual](http://www.abap-tutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/massmaintenance.pdf) for making background changing task with `MASS`.

Comment: Thanks for this, led me to a solution that I can use. (in my comment to the original question)    :)